# Markov inequality applied to two random variables

Tags: probability

$X_1, X_2, ..., X_m$ is a stochastic process which takes only positive values. $T$ is a stopping time adapted to the filtration generated by $X$

I have encountered this formula:

$P(T \leq n, X_T > \alpha) \leq \mathbb{E}(\frac{X_T}{\alpha}1_{T \leq n})$

I see that it is Markov inequality, but I don't udnerstand how they can use it when probability of the event depends on two random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the event that $T\leq n$ and $X_T> \alpha$ implies that $1_{\{T\leq n\}} X_T> \alpha$, so the probability of the latter is an upper bound. Now use Markov.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as in the proof Markov's inequality we can  write $E\frac {X_T} {\alpha} 1_{T \leq  n} \geq E\frac {X_T} {\alpha} 1_{T \leq  n} 1_{X_T >\alpha} \geq E1_{T \leq  n} 1_{X_T >\alpha} =P(T \leq n, X_T >\alpha)$.